# WKInterfaceMap disable trigger to native Apple Watch Map

Tags: ios, watchkit

I had researched on this topic and stack says, there is no way to handle click event on the map.

As the title, any other way to disable the trigger to native map as it decrease the UX and change it to generate the map again onTap?

Deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure who said it's not possible but you can disable the tap but you have to use storyboard.  Just uncheck the `Enabled` checkbox under the Attribute Inspector and the map will not be tap enabled.

As per Apple Doc:

> A checkbox that indicates whether the map is enabled. When the map is
>   enabled, tapping it launches the Maps app and displays the currently
>   set location.

[image]

Comment: hey @rmp huge thanks for telling me, do you know anyway to handle the WKInterfaceMap onTap ??

Comment: Enable/Disable is the only option you have with `WKInterfaceMap` at this time, there is no way to override the onTap of the map.